# Loading Windows 8 Phone onto Mac showing as Unix Executable Files

Tags: macos, mac, video, windows-phone

I'm trying to get videos off my Nokia Windows 8 phone onto OSX using the Windows Phone app. When I import the videos it shows as Unix Executable Files and won't open in Preview/Itunes/Photos/etc.

How can I get the videos in a format I can use on my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Not opening is a function of being an executable that hasn't been blessed.  In a terminal

> chmod ugo-x <media_file_name(s)>

and then assuming the files are recognized and claimed by an app, they should open.